# flash as3 unicode support

Tags: actionscript-3

Can i load my own language as text in as3 textarea or labels from xml or from database. I want to display tamil in flash swf or in AIR APP. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Flash uses unicode by default, and I see no reasons to change that. If your text doesn't displays correctly, you need a font with such letters. Embed it into swf, use it in your textareas/labels and enjoy.

Comment: Specifically, it prefers to use UTF-8.